# Set D3.js circle report boundaries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to set up a visualization so that the higher value cells are with gravity forced to the top and left, but I'm having trouble keeping multiple circles within the boundaries of the div with red area. Can you help me solve this?

```
    function CreateCirclesOfProcessos(seletor, data, numWidth, numHeight) {

    let numBoundaryDiameter = 50;
    let numBoundaryRadius = 5;
    let numMaxRadius = 100;
    let numMargin = data.length * 10;
    let n = 50;
    
    const radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
        .range([0, numMaxRadius]);

    const radius = function (d) {
        return radiusScale(d.value);
    }

    let objNodes = CreateProcessosNodes(n, numBoundaryRadius, numBoundaryDiameter, data, numWidth, numHeight);

    let objGraphData = GetProcessosGraphData(radius, objNodes);

    const objSVG = seletor.append('svg')
        .attr("width", numWidth)
        .attr("height", numHeight + numMargin);

    let objGroup = objSVG.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 70 + ", " + 70 + ")");

    objGroup.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", numWidth)
        .attr("height", numHeight)
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("fill", "none");

    let objCircles = objGroup.selectAll("circle")
        .data(objGraphData.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    objCircles.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("fill", "#FF5532")
        .style("stroke", "white");           
}
```

Thanks!!
[This is my complete code on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renanbarbosa28/cx1n3ubw/2/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using [d3.forceLimit](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-force-limit), implementing the following code on my simulation method.

```
const wallForce = d3.forceLimit()
                    .radius(node => node.r)
                    .x0(0)
                    .x1(numWidth)
                    .y0(0)
                    .y1(numHeight);

const force = d3.forceSimulation()
                .nodes(objNodes)
                .force("x", d3.forceX().x(CoordinatePosition).strength(GetStrength))
                .force("y", d3.forceY().y(CoordinatePosition).strength(GetStrength))
                .force('many', d3.forceManyBody().strength(1))
                .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(numRadius).strength(2.5))
                .force('walls', wallForce)
                .stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply a custom tick function, and use it to keep items in bounds. We can also use `forceCenter` to keep items at the center:

```
const force = d3.forceSimulation(objNodes)
    .force("x", d3.forceX().x(CoordinatePosition).strength(GetStrength))
    .force("y", d3.forceY().y(CoordinatePosition).strength(GetStrength))
    .force('many', d3.forceManyBody().strength(2))
    .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(numRadius).strength(1))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter())
    .on('tick', () => {
        nodes.attr("cx", d => d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)))
             .attr("cy", d => d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)));
    })
    .stop();
```

where `nodes` represent your circles. In this case, you'll have to pass the `objCircles` selection from earlier in your code:

```
  let objCircles = objGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .data(objGraphData.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  let objGraphData = GetProcessosGraphData(radius, objNodes, objCircles);

  // ...

  function GetProcessosGraphData(numRadius, objNodes, nodes) {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: But my objcircles selection uses objGraphData.nodes in .data().